# SQL - substring function - num of parameters?

Tags: sql, substring

The client gave me the task to see what is wrong with his big query, why it's not working. I spotted the error - it's in this part of the query:

```
and value <> substring(value2, 4)
```

When I use this, the query is working as the client wants:

```
and value <> substring(value2, 5)
```

However, I Googled what `substring` in SQL means and found this article:

https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-string-functions/sql-server-substring-function/

But here we have two parameters inside `substring` and client uses only two. So, can someone explain the difference, or direct me to an article where I can find the answer?

Comment: `substring()` is available in Many DBMS's. So, for what DBMS you referring this function ?

Comment: In `MySQL`, third parameter is optional. So, the whole string will be returned (from the start position).

Comment: The article in the question refers to SQL Server, where you need 3 parameters for substring...If you are using a different dbms then you may not need all 3 parameters

Comment: thanks a lot!!!!!1

Comment: So which DBMS **are** you using?

Comment: im using heidsql

Comment: That's a SQL tool that can connect to many different database products. It's not a DBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In databases that accept the two argument form of substring, the substring takes from the second argument to the end of the string.  The counts starts at `1`, not `0`, so `substring(value, 1)` in these databases would extract the whole string.

With three arguments, a positive third argument is always a length.  I don't recall off-hand if a negative third argument is allowed in any databases.

SQL Server requires three arguments.